# Algorithm to search on differents fields with JPA in Java

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, search

I have two entities:

```
public abstract class ElementMap {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "coordinate")
@JsonManagedReference
private Coordinate coordinate;

private String name;[...]
```

and

```
public class Coordinate {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

private int x;
private int y;
@Column(name = "map_x")
private int mapX;
@Column(name = "map_y")
private int mapY;

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "coordinate")
@JsonBackReference
private ElementMap elementMap;[...]
```

In database, I have many elements
[(like this)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AM6oC.png) to fill differents lines.

And I want to create a service, which use a Coordinate object, to have an advanced search.

For example, if I put: **x=3 and map_y=5**, I want to find every lines *where x=3 AND map_y=5*.

And if I put: **x=3, map_y=5 and y=6**, I want to find every lines *where x=3 AND map_y=5 AND y=6*.

With Spring JPA, it's possible to create, in the interface *ElementMapRepository*, some methods like:

```
- findByCoordinateMapXAndCoordinateXAndCoordinateY
- findByCoordinateYAndCoordinateX
- findByCoordinateY
```

etc...

But there are so many interface to create to manage all cases.

So what is the best solution to do to create an advanced search for an object in Java Spring Boot and/or with JPA ?

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#specifications, https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#query-by-example, https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#core.extensions.querydsl

Comment: Thanks, I don't have the good way to find my answer

Comment: Then click on the links I gave you, and read the documentation. All these linked sections of the doc are different ways to do what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I find a good tutorial to answer to my question, with use of QueryDslPredicateExecutor.

http://www.baeldung.com/rest-api-search-language-spring-data-querydsl